# Bound on eigenvalues for subset of columns of projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, projection-matrices

I'm taking the product of an orthogonal projection matrix (symmetric), $P$, with a  diagonal matrix $D$ whose entries are either 0 or 1. So, $\tilde{P} = PD$ results in zeroing-out some of the columns of $P$.

I know that since both $P$ and $D$ have only 0s and 1s as eigenvalues, it must hold that $0 \leq \lambda_i \leq 1$ for any eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ of $\tilde{P}$ (as explained here: [Eigenvalues of real diagonal matrix times orthogonal projection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2649352/eigenvalues-of-real-diagonal-matrix-times-orthogonal-projection)).

My question is: since we are essentially selecting a subset of the columns of $P$, does this impose a more restrictive upper bound on the eigenvalues? Specifically, I'm trying to show that they must be strictly less than 1.

Comment: $1$ can be an eigenvalue of $PD$. Consider $P=I$ for instance. The spectral radius of $PD$ is less than $1$ if and only if the image of $D$ does not contain any eigenvector of $P$.